# MoveIt Rviz "No planning library loaded"

Tags: rviz, moveit, ogre, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all,

after finishing the "MoveIt! Setup Assistant" for my tx60l-robot I tried to start the rviz moveit plugin with following command:

```
roslaunch tx60l_moveit moveit_rviz.launch
```

Rviz starts, but there is no robot visible.

**The "moveit_rviz.launch"-file generated by the "MoveIt! Setup Assistant":**

```
<launch>

  <arg name="debug" default="false" />
  <arg unless="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="" />
  <arg     if="$(arg debug)" name="launch_prefix" value="gdb --ex run --args" />
  
  <node name="$(anon rviz)" launch-prefix="$(arg launch_prefix)" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find tx60l_moveit_config)/config/kinematics.yaml"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

There is no reference on my .urdf-file I used for the MoveIt! Setup Assistant" !
-> no robot can be displayed

**Though this [instruction](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/Rviz_Plugin/Details) shows a different kind of .launch-file (using pr2-robot):**

```
 <launch>
        <include file="$(find pr2_description)/robots/upload_pr2.launch"/>
        <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 odom_combined base_footprint 100" />
        <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
         <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
        </node>
        <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" respawn="true" output="screen" />
        <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
           <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
         </node>
        <include file="$(find pr2_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>
    </launch>
```

**My new launch file:**

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find tx60l_moveit)/launch/upload_tx60l.launch"/>
    <include file="$(find tx60l_moveit)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>
</launch>
```

upload_tx60l.launch:

```
<launch>
    <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find learning_urdf)/tx60l.xml" />
</launch>
```

**Edit:**

With my new launch-file Rviz starts finally. Obviously all nodes are loaded by the Moveit Assistant generated launch file (Though I cant detect them in there)

After starting Rviz I add "MotionPlanning" like described in this [tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Rviz_Plugin/Quick_Start).
Now my Robot is visible

But there is the hint: "no planning library loaded".
Have I to start Rviz with an additional parameter which defines the used planning library?

Also I cant select any "Planning Group"!

How can I solve that?
Or what information are relevant to help me?

**Edit:**

Now the OMPL is loaded, thx to Boris. But I dont get any interactive marker (is there a different way to set robot-poses?) for my robot-arm when I click on "Interact". When I load the pr2-demo it works. So the failure has to be hidden in my robot-config created with the "Setup Assistant". Is it because I didnt have defined an End-Effector?

**Edit:** Dave told me the problem is the end-effector. But I still cant solve it. I already tried all combinations. My robot is a simple arm of 6 links connected by 5 joints. I put all joints in one "arm-group" and the last link (link6) in another group called "end" but with no ki-solver, because its only one link. I think that's similar to [this tutorial](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/index.php/Groovy/PR2/Setup_Assistant/Quick_Start). Then I added an end-effector with the end-effector-group "end" and the parent link link 5. But there is still no interactive markers visible. What am I doing wrong?

Many Thanks in advance
viovio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53723/moveit-rviz-%22no-planning-library-loaded%22/) by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 117 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-07**:
Please do not modify your questions that much. It is very difficult to track the changes. If you have new info simply **add** it under section "Edit", including the modified versions of your files. For very long (more than one screen) logs please consider [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if it is a real cause of the problem, but you have duplicated `joint_state_publisher` node in your config.

Also, if understand correctly, TX60L is an industrial manipulator from Staubli that is supposed to be fixed, e.g to a floor. So in case you are not going to put it on wheels in your simulation you don't need odometry frame. Thus a more relevant tutorial for you would be the one from [ROS Industrial](http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot). There is a reference to `demo.launch` template where you should specify the name of your MoveIt generated package.

So, for example, I have the following `demo.launch` for Schunk LWA manipulator:

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find lwa_moveit_config)/config/lwa.urdf" />
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
  </node>
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
  <include file="$(find lwa_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="allow_trajectory_execution" value="false"/>
  </include>
  <include file="$(find lwa_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch"/>
</launch>
```

Hope it helps,

Boris

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-02-07**:
Thank you for your answer Boris. Meanwhile I solved my problem particulate (See my post). Unfortunately rviz loads no motion planing library.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-07**:
Please try the proposed launch file (don't forget to make changes according to your work environment). The one you are using now does not utilize planner, i.e. `move_group.launch` and of course there is no planning groups.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-06**:
Thx Boris, after adding it works. But I get no interactive markers after clicking on Interact.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-06**:
I'm having the same issue at the moment, planning works though. Also my case is 7-DOF arm with several additional `fixed` links and custom `IKFast` solver. So I'm unsure at the moment what causing this problem. Looks like some misconfiguration of planning groups in Setup Assistant.

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-08**:
Have you found a solution for the problem?

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-03-08**:
Not yet, it doesn't disturb me that much. However I did encounter this behaviour before and the issue was with non-complete configuration in MoveIt assistant, especially with the end-effector planning group. So if your arm has no gripper it can be the reason. Try to add a fake tool link in URDF.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to launch YOURROBOT_moveit_config/launch/move_group.launch first, before running the rviz launcher.

The move_group.launch file starts up the planning pipeline necessary for the Motion Planning Plugin to do actual planning. Additionally, it will load your URDF file for you, no need to use upload_tx60l.launch.

**Response to Edited Question:**
Yes, the interactive markers will not show up unless all the parameters to the end effector are setup correctly

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-05**:
I allready launch YOURROBOT_moveit_config/launch/move_group.launch first, before running the rviz launcher. Nethertheless I have to use upload_tx60l.launch, or I get the error that the urdf-file cant be found.

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-03-05**:
Ah, I see now in planning_context.launch that you need to change the first arg ("load_robot_description") to true. That should fix your problem

**Comment by [viovio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3084/viovio/) on 2013-03-06**:
Yes, you're right. Thx. Do you also have a solution for my missing interactive marker - problem (see my last edit) ?

**Comment by [Ioachim](https://answers.ros.org/users/21823/ioachim/) on 2015-03-16**:
Hello.
I want to start by saying that I am new to the Moveit programming.
I have a Cyton gamma 1500 robot rm and I managed to make the arm move with Rviz. I created another group for the gripper but i couldn't make the gripper to read from Rviz onlt from controller.yaml.
Can someone give me a hint?